# How to add&remove input text box dynamically?

Tags: javascript, forms, xhtml

Suppose there is a group of elements like:

```
<p>What's your question?</p>
<input type='text' name='question'/>
```

And there is a button:

```
<input type='button' value='Add' />
```

I want to implement that when I click the button, the group the elements will be created on the html page dynamically. Also beside the elements there is a remove button:

```
<input type='button' value='Remove' />
```

When I click it, the elements will be removed.

The process can be executed multiple times dynamically, and all these elements are contained in a form. After user input the answer, all information will be posted to another page.

I think this function can be implemented by js, but I don't know how to do it. Please provide some code. Thanks!

Comment: Did you even try searching? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+remove+input+[javascript]

Comment: are you using any library or framework? (jquery...)

Comment: I did, but didn't found that. Still thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use jQuery and do the add / remove operations on the button click

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button id='addButton'>Add</button>
    <button id='removeButton'>Remove</button>
</div>
<div id='target'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addButton').click(function () {
        var elem = $('<div></div>');
        elem.append('<p>What\'s your name</p>');
        elem.append('<input type="text">');
        $('#target').append(elem);
    }); 

    $('#removeButton').click(function () {
        $('#target div:last').remove();
    })
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XZqPa/

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked a number of times.  Search for "Javascript show hide element".

Personally, I would use the jQuery library, tag the input element or some div surrounding the markup that you wish to dynamically show and hide, with an ID tag and use code like:

```
$('#someuniqueid').hide();

$('#someuniqueid').show();
```

to hide and show your markup.  This solution assumes the input element is already in the page, JaredPar's solution dynamically creates your input element.  Both are just as good as each other - but jQuery makes this very easy.

If you want a vanilla js solution - see the other answers by searching for them - there are several to choose from.